# Tool for analyzing IIS web logs for troubleshooting

Tags: iis

I'm looking for some kind of tool that will let me slice and dice IIS web logs, for troubleshooting purposes...
All tools I've found are designed to analyze logs for a "Google Analytics" type of output, but what I want is more like "see all hits made from some IP", "see all hits to a specific ASHX file", things like that, to troubleshoot a few obscure bugs we are having with sessions...

Does anyone know of such a tool, or should I just roll my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use logparser. It is a free tool to analyze all kinds of logs including IIS logs.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Here is another great link.
http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Using-Logparser-Utility-Analyze-ExchangeIIS-Logs.html

Comment: Wow, that's so much more than I needed (and much harder to use, but it's great!)
Thank you!

Comment: When you start querying your raw logs and comparing the results to Google Analytics for the same time period you are likely to have a head-scratching large discrepency. Also FYI, IIS logs are in GMT by default wich you can shift to local time with logparser.

Answer (score 1):

Our group at work is suggesting logdog.  Open source, free, etc.  I don't have direct experience, yet, but it is my understanding that it operates in a very efficient way on different logs (syslogd, access.log, error.log).  You configure which logs to watch, how much, how often, what to look for.  It can then be configured to send out alerts.

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) is more heavyweight. But its free ( if your logs aren't huge). And its cute.

And there are always the plain find, findstr, grep's and such.